# How to get task out of asyncio event loop in a view?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In my web application written using aiohttp I have 2 endpoints. First is starting asyncio task which is infinite loop. The second one intended to cancell certain task. Since asyncio task doesn't have any id concept im a bit confused. 
Is it possible to save some identifier of the task in the database? 
Is it right way to do it or the lib already provided solution for this kind of problem?

## aiohttp_app/views.py

```
from aiohttp import web

import asyncio
import json


async def coro(frequency):
    while True:
         print('Infinite loop iteration')
         await asyncio.sleep(frequency)


def start_task(request):
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = event_loop.create_task(coro())
    # save some identifier of the task in the database to find it later
    response = dict()
    return web.json_response(json.dumps(response))


def stop_task(request):
     task = None  # here i must get a certain task outta event loop
     task.cancel()
     response = dict()
     return web.json_response(json.dumps(response))
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please add code, which you have tried

Comment: I didn't try any code. Please say what exactly you didn't understand that you need a code example and I'll give you all info I can.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically the part **Help others reproduce the problem**. Ideally you would provide the code that sets up two (trivial!) endpoints. In your case it would help us understand exactly how you create the task that you need canceled.

Comment: Thank you guys that you helping me ask better question. i edited my question body and added some code example to show where exactly i had some troubles

Answer (score 1):

You could generate simple monotonically increasing numeric IDs, and have a global dict that maps ID to task instance. The mapping would be removed when the coroutine is done. For example (untested):

```
import asyncio, itertools

_next_id = itertools.count().__next__
_tasks = {}

def make_task(corofn, *coroargs):
    task_id = _next_id()
    async def wrapped_coro():
        try:
            return await corofn(*coroargs)
        finally:
            del _tasks[task_id]
    task = asyncio.create_task(wrapped_coro())
    _tasks[task_id] = task
    return task_id, task

def get_task(task_id):
    return _tasks[task_id]
```

You could then use it in `start_task` and `stop_task`:

```
def start_task(request):
    task_id, _ = make_task(coro)
    response = {'task_id': task_id}
    return web.json_response(json.dumps(response))

def stop_task(request):
     task_id = json.loads(await request.text())['task_id']
     task = get_task(task_id)
     task.cancel()
     response = {}
     return web.json_response(json.dumps(response))
```